# Glitchy transform transition in Firefox when parent element changes from absolute to fixed

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've had a look around but couldn't find anyone else experiencing anything similar.

As the title states I'm getting a weird "glitch" in a transform transition when the parent element changes from absolute to fixed positioned ONLY in Firefox (looks completely fine in Chrome).

Thought I would throw it in here just in case someone has found a fix for this issue before.

OS: OS X El Capitan
Firefox version: 51.0.1

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNmJPK

Html:

```
<div class="menu">
  <button id="btn-menu" type="button">
    <span class="menu-bars"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#btn-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50px;
  right: 30px;
  height: 49px;
  width: 49px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  .menu-open & {
    border-color: transparent;
    position: fixed;
  }

  .menu-bars {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 21px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: .3s;

    &:before, &:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      transition: .3s;
    }

    &:before {
      top: -10px;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }

    &:after {
      bottom: -10px;
      transform-origin: 0 100%;
    }

    .menu-open & {
      background-color: transparent;

      &:before {
        top: -7px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }

      &:after {
        bottom: -7px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JQuery:

```
// Open/close menu
$('#btn-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing all transitions of `top, left, right, bottom` with `transform: translate()`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker ahh I didn't try that, thank you, I think I can get that to work!

Comment: Sweet, np. Yeah `transform` gets GPU acceleration, but top/left/right/bottom doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @MichaelCoker for the solution of using transforms instead of top, bottom. See updated codepen below.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgWpQa

```
    &:before {
        transform: translate(0, -10px);
    }

    &:after {
        transform: translate(0, 10px);
    }

    .menu-open & {
        background-color: transparent;

        &:before {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        &:after {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
    }
```